# Sound playback after loading gervill.jar

Tags: java, audio, playback

I have a Java app that plays .mid files, it works fine. But since I want to save .mid files as .wav files, I added gervill.jar to my app and wrote a method to convert mid to wav.

Now I've noticed a small problem when I play a .mid file : In a JList that lists the mid files, I can click and play those files one by one. Before I added the "gervill.jar" file to the project, it works fine, but now if one mid file is playing and I clicked on another mid file on the list, the current melody would choke a bit, as if it is stopping, then continue to play a fraction of a second of the current melody, then stop to play the new melody.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, any fix for it ?

Comment: Is it possible to create a reproducible example and add it to your question? At the moment it ambiguous if from where the problem may stem